# UITableView within a UIViewController - Data doesn't load

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I know that there are several posts around the www, but sadly I don't get the tableView to be loaded.
here is my code:

.h file

```
@interface ViewControllerSzenenLichter : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
 IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

I connected the IBOutlet with my tableview in the Storyboard

.m file

```
@interface ViewControllerSzenenLichter ()
@end
@implementation ViewControllerSzenenLichter
@synthesize tableView;
```

somewhere in the code I try to execute

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

which is executed(checked by Breakpoint)

but the method numberOfRowsInSection or numberOfSectionsInTableView are never called!

As mentioned I found a lot of tutorials in the web, but I can't solve the Problem.

thanks

Comment: Roload the bigger `tableView` each time you reload the smaller `tableView`

Comment: could you be more specific what you mean with 'bigger' and 'smaller' tableView?

Comment: Don't forget to set the `delegate` & `datasource` of the `UITableView` as well.

Comment: did you connected the delegate in xib?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem! What is the common way to do this? I just added 
`self.tableView.dataSource=self;
self.tableView.delegate=self;`
to my viewDidLoad method

Comment: What you did is pretty correct but since you started with `Storyboard` you could do it there. Right click & drag from the `UITableView` to the `UIViewController` and set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your child `tableView` is basically a cell of your parent `tableView`.

So, unless you reload your parent `tableView`, the cell will not update, and hence, the child `tableView` will not be plotted.

```
[childTableView reloadData];
[parentTableView reloadData];
```

EDIT :
And @Desdenova is right. Make sure you set your `delegate` and `data source` to `self` or whatever class manages the tables.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard Right click over the table you will see datasource and delegates as the first two options.Connect both to the viewcontroller (same as you did for outlet connection) and run again.

The final table connections will be like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you connect one IBOutlet and use another when reload data: You have two ivars `tableView` (you create it manualy) and `_tableView` (created compiler and links with `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`), I don't now which one will be shown as TableView property of file owner in InterfaceBuilder. Try remove `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` ivar and reconnect Table in IB

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are setting delegate in xib file or implementation file for your table. If still not working, check the code where you are reloading table. If main thread is busy doing something else, it will not call any of the delegate method of UITableView. So when the code finishes, then reload tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your TableView to the File's Owner by the delegate and datasource...

I think your problem will be solved. Here is a picture for your batter understanding...

[image: Connecting your TableView to the File's Owner]